# Why does using += on a nullable type result in a FORWARD_NULL defect

Tags: c#, nullable, static-analysis, coverity

No doubt there are other, perhaps better ways to do this, but I'm trying to understand what is going on here.

In the below example, coverity is reporting a FORWARD_NULL defect on the fourth line.

```
double? foo = null;
double bar = 1.23;
foo += bar;
System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(foo,bar);
```

it reports:

> assign_zero: Assigning: foo = null.

on the foo += bar line.

in [+= Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator), I see that **x += y** is equivalent to **x = x + y**, and in [Using nullable types (C+ Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types#see-also), I see that

> These operators *[the binary operator]* produce a null value if one or both operands are
>   null

so is that what is going on?  foo += bar becomes foo = foo + bar and since foo is null, foo + bar is null?

Comment: Yeah, foo remains as null

Comment: Is the *defect* being reported on line three, or is line three *evidence* for a defect that comes later? Normally the forward null defect is reported at the location where a null dereference can throw, but there's no such dereference here.

Comment: @Eric Lippert you are correct.  The  defect is reported a few lines later where foo is being dereferenced.  I'll update the question

Comment: OK good, but the program fragment you gave shouldn't even *compile*. `Point` takes a double, not a nullable double. There's no reason to run code through Coverity if it doesn't even compile!

Answer (score 5):

> so is that what is going on? foo += bar becomes foo = foo + bar and
>   since foo is null, foo + bar is null?

Yes.